# Warning: fopen(welcome.txt) [function.fopen]: failed to open stream:

Tags: php, file

how to remove this error is this possible to control this error?

```
<?php
$file=fopen("welcome.txt","r");
?>
```

Comment: Please include the full error message in the question (and read it :)). The bit currently missing is why it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know exactly what you are looking for but you can add condition to check either file exists or not. maybe that'll solve your problem

```
<?php
if(!file_exists("welcome.txt")) {
  die("File not found");
} else {
  $file=fopen("welcome.txt","r");
}
?>
```

Comment: Please note that, apart from the potential race condition (the file may stop being available right after the existence check), opening a file can fail for a number of reasons such as insufficient permissions or I/O errors. `file_exists()` is fine (it catches a potentially common error) but it can't be the only check.

Answer (score 2):

In the [`fopen()` manual page](https://php.net/fopen) we can read (emphasis mine):

> **Return Values**
>
> Returns a file pointer resource on success, **or `FALSE` on failure**
>
> **Errors/Exceptions**
>
> Upon failure, an `E_WARNING` is emitted.

So:

```
$file = fopen("welcome.txt","r");
if ($file) {
    // Everything's fine
} else {
    // Error happened
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The same happened here.
I just deleted the ".txt" extension from the file and kept the one in the code and it worked.